# Strange Problem with SourceSerifPro

Tags: fonts, pdf, sourcesanspro

Does anyone understand what is going on here.

I have the following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8pt,a5paper,twoside,DIV=14,BCOR=10mm,chapterprefix=off]{scrreprt}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[default,regular,black]{sourceserifpro}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Strange non-embedded fonts}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
Test

\end{document}
```

[image: Fonts used in PDF generated from above example using MiKTeX on Windows]

When compiling on overleaf I get the following:

[image: Result of same code on overleaf]

What is wrong with my Tex Installation?

Comment: Have you installed `cm-super`? If not, do it. BTW: The problem does almost not depend on `sourceserifpro`. Almost, because the package also activates font encoding `T1` for `pdflatex`. This results in loading european computer modern sans serif as default sans serif font. And without `cm-super` this is a bitmap font. As an alternative load `lmodern` before `sourceserifpro`.

Comment: Should I somewhere mark this problem as solved?